# Moment JS days difference issue

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm calculating the days difference between two dates using `moment.js`, but seems it wasn't calculated correctly.

```
const moment1 = moment(new Date('2020-04-05'));
const moment2 = moment(new Date('2020-01-06'));
const diff = moment1.diff(moment2 , 'days');
console.log(diff);
```

The output is 89 whereas the actual value should be 90. Specifically, if I change moment1 to '2020-04-04', the output is still 89. But after '2020-04-05' the value is always 1 day less than the actual value. Why?

Comment: I checked it in http://jsfiddle.net/brandonscript/rLjQx/ . .. it shows 90.

Comment: I checked too it shows 89

Comment: copy pasted to broweser console on momenjs.com (where moment is available) and got 90

Comment: Whats your timezone area ?

Comment: +0900, but results should not be able to differ depending on from which timezone you compare two specific dates. Are you sure there isn't any other code you are not showing us?

Comment: Yea I did exactly the same in http://jsfiddle.net/brandonscript/rLjQx/ and got 89. My timezone is AEST in Sydney

Comment: @Alex Wang I get 90 when running your code. What do you get in this jsfiddle that converts to ISO string? http://jsfiddle.net/uhdqtpby/

Comment: @jdaz I opened yours and got "2020-04-05T00:00:00.000Z"
"2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z"
89

Comment: I was getting 90 before (US Pacific time zone), but I changed my system time zone to AEST and now I get 89 as well. If you run `const diff = moment1.diff(moment2 , 'hours');` though, you get 2160 hours, which is 90 days! Digging into the actual moment source, it looks like days has an extra calculation that is supposed to make up for daylight saving time. If you run `const diff = moment1.diff(moment2 , 'days', true);`, you get 89.9583, which is 90 days minus 1 hour. I'll submit a bug report for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass `dates` you are checking for difference instead of using `new Date()` There is not requirement to use `new Date()` at all

Simple pass the date as string to moment and you will have 90 days.

Here is what `moment.js` [diff](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/) says.

Run snippet below.

```js
const moment1 = moment('2020-04-05');
const moment2 = moment('2020-01-06');
const diff = moment1.diff(moment2 , 'days')
console.log(diff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yea this returns 90. But still confused why the previous one returns 89..

Comment: Because you were using `new Date()` function which return the convert the date again not on timezone thing. Just use moment.js with dates you want to use and pass them as strings - Cheers.

Comment: But he did the same with both dates. how can that ever be explained by the "timezone thing?". I think your answer is good, I'm just still curious!  And moment accepts date-objects. That could break an app in a different timezone, if that's true.

Comment: Yeah this answer works perfect but still confused if that is a bug of momentjs, since both '2020-04-05' and '2020-04-04' return 89 days

Comment: @AlexWang Its not a bug of moment you have go to off moment official documentation to see how they are using to get `diff` which i have linked above as well. The new Date function create a `new date` where months are calculated as 0-11 not 1-12 so when you add `new date()` with moment its goes back one month and give you days of that previous month which could be 31. You can read about [new Date() here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on MDN official. Hope this makes sense.